# Is this proof of "binomial coefficients are always natural numbers" correct?

Tags: induction

I'm a high school graduate, who has started doing Spivak's Calculus, for fun. I was struggling a bit with a certain question on proving the above stated fact using Principle of Mathematic Indutction.
I came up with the following proof, but am unsure since it is very unlike previous PMI questions I've done.

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k - 1}$$
For $n = 1$
$$\binom{1}{k} = \binom{1}{0}\space or \space \binom{1}{1} = 1$$
Therefore $\binom{n}{k}$ is a natural number when $n = 1$.

Assumption: $\binom{n}{k}$ is a natural number for all $k\in \{1, 2, \dots,n\}$
$$\binom{n + 1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1}$$.
$\binom{n}{k}$ is a natural number from the previous argument. The same applies to $\binom{n}{k - 1}$.
The remaining two possible values of $k$ are $n + 1$, $0$.
$$\binom{n+1}{0} = \binom{n+1}{n+1} = 1$$.
Therefore all the possible values of $\binom{n + 1}{k}$ are natural numbers.
Therefore, $\binom{n}{k}$ is always a natural number by induction.

Comment: With this rule, it is clear that Pascal's triangle can be constructed upto any level and the entries must all be positive integers. So, you can consider it to be a proof.

Comment: You seem to be confusing induction on $n$ with induction on $k$. How are the binomial coefficients defined, is it a factorial definition or another? Edit: Sorry, I can see you are actually inducting on $n$ now, I got confused by the wording.

Comment: State your hypotheses more clearly at the beginning.

Comment: @Arby I was unable to find a way to properly induct on $k$, which is why I resorted to $n$, but then $k$ has to be accounted for, so I resorted to proving that $\binom{n + 1}{k}$ was an integer for all possible $k$ assuming that $\binom{n}{k}$  was an integer for all $k$. If you have any suggestions on how to improve the above mentioned proof, please mention them/

Comment: We need to know what can be assumed. "Given this definition of binomial coefficients, prove they are always natural numbers."

Comment: By the way, I was wrong when I initially said you inducted wrongly on $k$. You didn't say something like "Assume the proposition is true for all natural numbers up to $n$, so I got confused. My bad.

Comment: @Arby I don't quite understand your previous comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean you inducted on $n$ correctly.

Comment: I got confused initially by your wording in the second induction step. Perhaps a better way to phrase it would be "Assume for every natural number up to $n$, $\binom n k$ is a natural number for all $k\in \{1, 2, \dots,n\}$". If you have already proved the addition property you have used, $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k - 1}$, the rest of the proof looks good to me.

Comment: @Arby Oh, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally your proof is correct(*). However what's missing is the definition of the binomial coefficient, that is what do $\binom{n}{k}$ mean? There's two ways to do that (perhaps more). One is to define it using the pascal triangle rule (recursive definition):

$$\binom{n}0 = \binom{n}{n} = 1$$
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}$$

With that definition your proof is straight forward as it relies on these identities.

Another way to define binomial coefficients is to define it as

$$\binom{n}{k} = {n!\over k! (n-k)!}$$

with this definition you must prove that the required identities hold, especially that $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}$. However that is quite straight forward:

$$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = {n! \over k! (n-k)!} + {n!\over (k-1)!(n-k+1)!} 
\\ = {n! (n-k+1) \over k! (n-k+1)!} + {n!k\over k!(n-k+1)!}
\\ = {n! (n-k+1) + n!k\over k! (n-k+1)!} 
\\= {(n+1)!\over k! (n-k+1)!} = \binom{n+1}{k}$$

(*) well almost, you have that it's allowed for $n=0$ in $\binom{n}{k}$, so you should have included the fact that $\binom{0}{0} = 1$ is a natural number.